# How can we treat dy and dx as quantities?

Tags: calculus

It is very common in non-rigorous calculus classes to perform operations of the form $$\frac{dy}{dx} = f'\left(x\right) \implies dy = f'\left(x\right) dx$$ As if these are simply numbers. How is this formally dealt with? From the minimal understanding I have, people have gone out of their way to develop the hyperreal numbers to formalise procedures such as this. Is that all there is to it?

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before

Comment: @Buraian . +1 Please vote to close .

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio) and many other similar questions.